# Функция преобразования long int в строку С

Tags: c, строки, преобразование-типов

Нужно преобразовать целое число типа `long int` в Си строку. Скажите, есть ли готовые решения даной задачи в библиотеках Си?

Comment: `snprintf` например

Comment: Если будете активно использовать [это](http://pastebin.com/zaNt0Y8C), то может оно и станет стандартным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция `sprintf` и строка `%ld` вам помогут.

Бывают нестандартные расширения - типа `itoa`, но стандартное переносимое преобразование - через `sprintf`.